# WSO2 Identity server OAuth 2 support

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are testing out WSO2's identity server. The features list shows that it supports OAuth 2, but I cannot seem to find any config options in the admin to determine the use of oAuth2. When I register my application, the registration information seems to suggest its oAuth 1. Can anyone confirm whether version 3.2.3 support oauth 2?

Answer (score 0):

No. The current version does not support OAuth 2. It is coming in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

I think WSO2 identity server version  4.0.0 onward this Oauth 2.0 is supported. Go to the IS home -> Service provider -> inbound Authentication Configuration ->
OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration 
and click Configure.
[image]

refer this link [oauth 2.0 with WSO2 identity server](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/OpenID+Connect+with+the+WSO2+Identity+Server+and+WSO2+OAuth2+Playground) for  latest version.